# When I tried to create a block in the testnet block chain network solidity created discontinuous blocks for every request

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am new to block chain. I tried to understand how the blocks are created in the block chain. So that I have tried simple smart contract in solidity and deployed the contract in testnet(Ropsten network). While execution of the contract I have noticed that blocks are created in a discontinuous manner.

Smart contract code:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.12;

contract Bank{
    int balance;

    constructor() public {
        balance=1;
    }

    function getBalance() view public returns(int){
        return balance;
    }
    function withDraw(int amount) public returns(string memory) {
        if(balance>=amount){
            balance-=amount;
            return "success";
        }
        else{
            return "out of balance";
        }
    }
    function depositAmount(int amount) public{
        balance+=amount;
    }
}

For example : Smart contract deployed block number --> 12003155,
              While calling the depositAmount function it created a block --> 12003210,
              While calling the withDraw function it created a block --> 12003222
```

My Question : why for every request it creating a discontinuous block instead of creating a continuous block ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum block number increase by 1 each time, and this can be seen on [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/blocks). The block number indicates the length of the blockchain.

The reason why you don't see this in your case is because your transactions are mined in different blocks. So your contract is deployed in block `#12003155`, then for 55 blocks the network is busy mining other people's transactions (block number is still increasing by 1), and then the call to `depositAmount()` is included in block `#12003210` and is mined.